# How to pass kwargs with function calls without immediate execution

Tags: python, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I want to pass a dict of function calls with function arguments as kwargs to another function. Unfortunately the passed functions get executed immediately rather than passed as the following example illustrates:

```
def info(info='NO INFO'):  # just a test function
    print(); print('\'', info, '\'', sep=""); print()

kwargs = {'one': info('executed one'), 'two': info('executed two')}
```

which results in:

```
'executed one'


'executed two'
```

How can I prevent these arguments from being executed and just passed on?

Comment: `info()` doesn't even return anything. What are you expecting the argument values to be when you pass it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a function, you're passing the result of calling the function. Python has to call the function(s) as soon as it reaches that line: `kwargs = {'one': info('executed one'), 'two': info('executed two')}` in order to know what the values are in the dict (which in this case are both `None` - clearly not what you intend).

As I said, you need to pass an actual function, which can be easily done with (for example, there are other ways) lambdas - lambdas with no arguments are not common but are allowed:

```
kwargs = {'one': (lambda: info('executed one')), 'two': (lambda: info('executed two'))}
```

Comment: But then whatever he passes `kwargs` to needs to know that it has to call the values, not just refer to them.

Comment: Yes, of course. For me that was implicit in the original question: that the OP wanted to pass functions in a dictionary to call later, rather than have the functions called immediately as in the faulty attempt. Perhaps I've misunderstood, but if so I hope the OP will clarify.

Comment: I doubt he understands any of that. I think he wants to do something like `someFun(**kwargs)`

Comment: This seems to work. 
`code`
kwargs = {'one': (lambda: info('executed one')), 'two': (lambda: info('executed two'))}
print(kwargs.keys())
kwargs['one']()
`code`

Output:

dict_keys(['one', 'two'])
kwargs['one']()

Comment: I had a bit of a problem formatting the above comment. Here's an improved one:

What I'm trying to do is create a thread that has a target function with a variable number of function calls passed as a dict. The proposed solution by @RobinZigmond seems to work. The statement 'kwargs['one']()' yields 
'executed one' which is the result of the function call.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for providing a solution so quickly.

Comment: Thanks, and no problem :)